# Determine type (node, string) of xpath output from query

Tags: python, xpath, types, lxml

Is there a way of determining, independent of the XML document, the type of the returned values from xpath? Specifically, I'm using lxml.

Examples:

- `//a` and `//b[a/@href]` will always return a list of zero or more elements.
- `//a/text()` and `//a/@href` will always return a list of zero or more strings.

Whilst I can think of various ways of trying to analyse these, it feels like trying to reinvent the wheel. Is there a better way of doing this?

**Background**

I'm bored of having to catch exceptions when it turns out that there aren't any `a` tags and I've written `root.xpath('//a')[0]`. And I don't want to just blindly catch everything. So I've written a set of functions that always return something of the right type. The `cssselector` and `attrib` replacements work just fine, but I can't fulfill the expectations of the output of `xpath` without knowing what that output should be.

If you really care, here's my code. https://scraperwiki.com/editor/raw/irked

Comment: If you don't want to catch exceptions, store the list returned from the xpath and check the length. Or just use the right XPath to get the first element: `root.xpath('//a[1]')`

Comment: Actually, all four of your expressions return lists of nodes. Element nodes for the first two, text nodes for the third, attribute nodes for the fourth.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your XPath expression like `//b[a/@href]` is static, is will always return the same type. (A list of elements, in this case.) You only want to know if the list is empty or not. A simple `if` statement can do that:

```
results = document.xpath('//b[a/@href]')
if results:
    do_something(results[0]
else:
    no_result()
```